# what is the zend dojo form combo select auto fill function syntax?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I am using zend dojo form and would like to fill the comboselect options from year 1911 to 2011.
I looked up this function for auto fill in the php manual but it does not work within ZF dojo form.
I get this error message

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in Signup.php on line 13

```
  //options declaration
 protected $_yearOptions = array_fill(

1911,101,'year');



 //adding combo element

  $this->addElement(
    'ComboBox',
    'comboyr',
    array(
    'label' =>'Birthyear',
    'value' =>'',
    'autocomplete' => false,
    'multioptions' => $this->_yearOptions,

    )

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 13 in your Signup.php file must be the protected $_yearOptions property. You cannot use functions when setting properties in classes. You must do something like this:

```
protected $_yearOptions = array();

protected function _getYearOptions () {
    if ( empty($this->_yearOptions) ) { $this->_yearOptions = array_fill(1911,101,'year'); }
    return $this->_yearOptions;
}
```

and then in your addElement you'll have this line instead

```
'multioptions' => $this->_getYearOptions(),
```

You may also use something different then array_fill. I don't think the result is what you are looking for.